# Label point on PCA decision surface - SVM

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I just created a PCA decision surfare for Support Vector Machine.

I want to see label for each point.
Example: I want to click on a point and read which row is; example 1 point represent Italy, 1 point represent Albania and so on.

This is my code (not interactive).

```
clf_svm = SVC(random_state=42, C=100, gamma=1)
clf_svm.fit(pca_train_scaled, y_train)

X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_train_scaled)
test_pc1_coords = X_test_pca[:, 0] 
test_pc2_coords = X_test_pca[:, 1]


x_min = test_pc1_coords.min() - 1
x_max = test_pc1_coords.max() + 1

y_min = test_pc2_coords.min() - 1
y_max = test_pc2_coords.max() + 1

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start=x_min, stop=x_max, step=0.1),
                     np.arange(start=y_min, stop=y_max, step=0.1))


Z = clf_svm.predict(np.column_stack((xx.ravel(), yy.ravel())))

Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.1)

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#e41a1c', '#4daf4a'])

scatter = ax.scatter(test_pc1_coords, test_pc2_coords, c=y_train, 
               cmap=cmap, 
               s=100, 
               edgecolors='k', ## 'k' = black
               alpha=0.7)

legend = ax.legend(scatter.legend_elements()[0], 
                   scatter.legend_elements()[1],
                    loc="upper right")
legend.get_texts()[0].set_text("No Default")
legend.get_texts()[1].set_text("Default")

ax.set_ylabel('PC2')
ax.set_xlabel('PC1')
ax.set_title('Decison surface using the PCA transformed/projected features')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think `ax.annotate(str(label[i]), (x[i], y[i]))` may help you do this with a `for` loop

Comment: What is your exact question? This is a partial requirements dump at best

Comment: @RedaElHail thank you! how can apply your string to this code? 
label and i, means for?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I want to understand for each point, which row of database is associated to understand if single row (single Country in my case) will default or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an interactive plot, I recommend you to use `plotly`

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()
```

This will give an interactive plot, where each time you put cursor on points you get the values.

For more information, visit this [page](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/)

EDIT: In your case, I presume it would look like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

st_pc1_coords = np.arange(3) # example data
test_pc2_coords = [3,4,1]  # example data
country = np.array(['italy','Morocco','Spain'])

df  = pd.DataFrame(data= [test_pc1_coords,test_pc2_coords,country],  
                           index = ['x','y','country'])
df = df.T                
fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", hover_data=['country'])
fig.show()
```

where `df` is a data frame with 3 columns which are `test_pc1_coords`, `test_pc2_coords` and `country`

Comment: How can adapt this, to my code? I had some difficulties...just tried this way

Comment: To use plotly, you will need to construct a pandas data frame containing `x` and `y`  positions of every points and the corresponding country (Italy or Albania), then use the `scatter` function with the constructed data frame and the right parameters.

Comment: The problem is that i'm using a SVM and I want to show a 22 dimensional graph in a 2 dimensional graph.
So, I tried to run this:
```import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(test_pc1_coords, test_pc2_coords)
fig.show() ```
but it's not working because there are some problems on the decision surface (see previous graph) and so on..

Comment: When I use ```Hover_data```, I receive an error: 
```ValueError: Value of 'hover_data_0' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width', 'species', 'species_id'] but received: CountryName```

Moreover, I'm working now with this code, but is still incomplete because I want to show pink area (=predicted area) as similar to previous graph, and understand at which point correspond a country.

```import plotly.express as px 

fig = px.scatter(df, test_pc1_coords, test_pc2_coords, y_train) 

fig.show()```

Comment: @GiovanniPontonio I think this error comes because the code I gave was loading the `iris` dataset in `df`. So replace `df = px.data.iris()` by `df  = pd.DataFrame(data= [test_pc1_coords,test_pc2_coords,coutries],  columns = ['x','y','country'])`. As note,  `test_pc2_coords` and `test_pc2_coords` should be numpy arrays

Comment: @GiovanniPontonio I updated my answer with a functioning example code.